# Do something after all ajax posts request are done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that does something like this

```
for(i = 0; i< n; i++){
  for(j = 0; j<m; j++){
     $.post('/post', {
       ...
     }
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like an alert only after every post request is done?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: If you have a variable number of requests, you can pair the `$.when` call with the apply method to give it a variable array, containing all the promises.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Use the .done callback to check a variable: example https://plnkr.co/edit/AXlZ7eERmeYns1VE5m3u?p=preview

Comment: That works. Thanks @scotty3